# Is there a way to copy the answers of a test form to a pdf once the user submits his answers?

Tags: php, html, mpdf

So my project is about an online test that once it's answered, phpmailer will send the total number of the correct answers to a specific email.
I want to know if it's possible that with radio input fields, once its all answered, the submit button could make a copy of all of the form with the chosen answers and saved them to a pdf, kinda like taking a screenshot of the whole webpage.
Code example:

```html
<div class="Pregunta">
    <div>1. I am</div>
    <div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="p1r" value="0" required aria-required="true"> 12 years old </div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="p1r" value="1" required aria-required="true">15 years old</div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="p1r" value="2" required aria-required="true">18 years old</div>
        <div><input type="radio" name="p1r" value="3" required aria-required="true">20 years old</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using HTML, PHP 5.7 and tried using mpdf library but I can only save the text inputs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, just the value of your form element is submitted, not the text right next to it. The only solution to this is to parse your HTML document or have an array of answers in your PHP source code.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and show us what you have tried that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this,

1) Instead of standard form submit, add click handler for the submit button. In this function populate the html content needed and trigger download. After that submit data to server side via AJAX.

2) Let the form get submitted to server PHP end. It will be posting only the input values to the PHP side. After results processed in server side, form the html/pdf using PHP and echo/print to client side for download.